# responsive image links

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid

Im trying to make a button responsive and scale to the browser size.

I did set the image as a background image on the  tag but didn't seem to be getting the desired effect. I' am now using the image inline with the following code.

**HTML**

```
<section class="desktop">
    <img class="logo" src="styles/css/images/oatbook.png" title="OATBook | Oral Anticoagulant Therapy">
    <a class="downloada" href="#"><img class="downloadimg" src="styles/css/images/download.png" title="OATBook | Oral Anticoagulant Therapy">sadf</a>
        </section><!-- desktop END -->
```

**CSS**

```
 a.downloada {
    background: aqua;
    max-width: 63%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-indent: -4000px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
img.downloadimg {
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -4000px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

**Live Example**
http://www.oatbook.co.uk/preview/

The problem is its currently responsive with the width, but displaying the whole sprite as the height seems to remain the same.

Open to other suggestions of best practise

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out **[Stretchy Sprites](http://tobyj.net/responsive-sprites)** (instructions & demo)

This method allows sprites to be resized proportionately, and doesn't rely on `background-size` which is only supported in newer browsers. No javascript, just HTML/CSS.

It works using a spacer image which is proportionate to your sprite.

Answer (score 0):

Close the `<img>` tag by adding a slash before a closing angle bracket:

```
 <img src="styles/css/images/download.png" />
                                           ^
```